# Describing the Bool-And monoid in terms of categories

Tags: category-theory

Normally I put the question before the context, but in this case I want to admit
the possibility that the context and my understanding nullify the question.
Plus it helps me think through my question.

I recently started reading [Category Theory for Programmers (Bartosz
Milewski)](https://github.com/hmemcpy/milewski-ctfp-pdf/), and this is my
understanding of categories: they are "algebraic structures" which consist of
objects and arrows/morphisms between those objects. The morphisms have to obey
the laws of associativity, so

$$ a \rightarrow ( b \rightarrow c ) = ( a \rightarrow b ) \rightarrow c $$

And there must be an identity morphism for each object.

Now, Milewski goes on to explain that monoids (which I'm pretty comfortable with
in the set-theoretic sense) are also viewable as categories. This is the part I
am having trouble with. One of the exercises in the book is to consider the
Boolean-and monoid (booleans with the and operator) as a category:

> Represent the Bool monoid with the AND operator as a category: List the
>   morphisms and their rules of composition.

I want to give some examples, which I'll do in a SML (though I'll borrow Haskell names).

The monoid could be described set-theoretically with the following signature:

```
signature MONOID = sig
  type m
  val mempty : m
  val mappend : m -> m -> m
end
```

Further, the monoid for booleans with the and operator would be given as

```
structure BoolAnd : MONOID = struct
  type m = bool
  val mempty = true
  fun mappend x y = x andalso y
end
```

So, here is my understanding of this monoid as a category and its morphisms: is
it correct?

- The objects in the category are booleans (true and false) and functions from
  booleans to booleans
- `BoolAnd.mappend` is a morphism from the former to the latter
- `mappend true` is an identity morphism for the function objects in the
  category (I say "an" because isn't the actual identity function `fun id x = x`
  also an identity morphism for the functions, thanks to polymorphic types? Or
  does that not count in category-land? I know that `mappend true` is equivalent
  to the identity function under composition of functions with type `bool -> bool`.)
- the identity morphism for boolean objects appears to be just `fun id (b:bool) = b`
- the given identity morphisms should be associative:

```
(* example, not proof *)
- open BoolAnd;
- (id o (mappend true)) o not;
val it = fn : bool -> bool
- it false;
val it = true
- id o ((mappend true) o not);
val it = fn : bool -> bool
- it false;
val it = true
```

The rules of composition seem to be that `mappend true` is the identity, while
`mappend false` is a "sink" of sorts, causing the resulting function to always
return false. But `id` and `mappend` don't directly compose, because the types
do not align (when `id` is specialized to booleans, as in the bullets above).

Am I missing something? Is something wrong? Did I give too much detail (there
seems to be an emphasis on avoiding digging in to the objects too much)?

I ask this both to confirm my understanding so that I have a good foundation for
the remainder of the book and also because it took me a long time to identify
the objects and morphisms at work; some of them I am still shaky about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monoids are *one-object* categories. The elements are morphisms, monoid multiplication is composition and the monoid identity is the identity morphism.

In the case of Booleans-with-AND the monoid is $M = (\{\top, \bot\}, \land, \top)$. The category therefore has a single object (we could call it $M$) with two morphisms $\top : M \to M$ and $\bot : M \to M$. Composition is given by $\land$ and the identity morphism is $\top$.

---

To give a little more context, there is a way to view a monoid in such a way that the objects are the elements of the monoid: as a discrete (no non-identity morphisms) monoidal category. *Category Theory for Programmers* covers the topic of monoidal categories in Chapter 22, "Monads Categorically".

Comment: I see how composition and identity work in this construction, but I’m unsure how to interpret top/true as an arrow from M to M (naïvely, I am attempting to consider a function, perhaps due to the suggestive notation, but is there a better interpretation?). Given that there is a single object M, of course the morphisms have to go from M to M, but I cant make heads or tails of how true and false fit into that

Comment: Morphisms are completely abstract: in general, they are not functions (though in certain cases, like the category of sets, they happen to be functions). Illustrative examples of this are monoids as one-object categories, and the category of matrices (in which *morphisms* are matrices). Remember that in the definition of a category, the morphisms from an object $A$ to an object $B$ form *some* set: there's no requirement for them to be functions or similar. If you have some things that can be composed, they can be morphisms in a category.

Comment: The fact the morphisms in this example go from $M$ to $M$ doesn't really *mean* anything (though it suggests that morphisms in a category may be thought of "generalised elements" in some sense). It's simply a repackaging of the data of a monoid into the data of a category. You could call the single object whatever you like: it's simply there to provide a domain and codomain for the morphisms.

Comment: Hm.. you’ve given me a lot to think about. Category of matrices makes sense from my linear algebra days. But if they aren’t necessarily function-like, how do they domain/codomain? Perhaps my definition of those terms is too restrictive. // Though again I do see the necessity of allowing M -> M ( -> M...) for composition purposes.

Comment: Your answer suggests to me that the monoid of natural numbers together with addition, when viewed as a category, contains morphisms (the natural numbers) with an identity morphism of 0 and composition via +. Milewski doesn’t explain this well, viewing the morphisms in a hand-wavy way as « adder functions » with function composition as an analogue for addition.

Comment: The category of matrices is [described here](https://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2008/06/02/the-category-of-matrices-i/). The objects are natural numbers, and a morphism from $m$ to $n$ is an $n \times m$ matrix. Composition is matrix multiplication. Your description of the monoid of natural numbers is correct.

Comment: @varkor, could you please give some info about the symbol you used? Specifically, what are `\top` and `\bot`?

Comment: @Enrico: $\top$ and $\bot$ stand for "true" and "false" respectively (see, for instance, [the Wikipedia page for truth values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_value)).

Comment: @varkor could you explain how happens that they are both elements of the Bool object M **and** morphisms from M to M?

Comment: @Enrico: the category has a single hom-set (from the unique object to itself). We can choose any set for a hom-set: in particular, we can take the underlying set of the monoid. So we're using the same set for two purposes (elements of the monoid, and morphisms of the category).

Comment: I don't understand. The hom-set contains morphisms, right? Morphisms are arrows, i.e. they go from something to something(else). ⊤ is a value (the other is ⊥) inside the object that you called M, not an arrow. What does `⊤ : M -> M` mean, then?

Comment: @Enrico: The object $M$ doesn't "contain" anything. It's simply a symbol. There's a single hom-set $\mathrm{Hom}(M, M)$ from $M$ to $M$, and it is this set that is equal to $\{ \top, \bot \}$. The elements $\top$ and $\bot$ thus represent morphisms, and though they don't themselves contain source and target information, they lie in a set that does, which establishes that they both have source and target $M$.